# iPhone didSelectRowAtIndexPath not invoke for cells number 10, 20,30

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

here is the thing. I have a `tableview` with a variable number of `rows`. When you tap one of them, a detail view is shown.

Everything is ok if you tapped rows from 0 to 9, 11 to 19, 21 to 29 etc... But it doesn't work for rows number `10, 20, 30` etc... Even a long tap is detected on this rows, so an `alert` is shown, in order to delete the row if necessary (and I can remove it without problems), but `didselectrowatindexpath` is Never called.

I think is something involved that the `tableview` only keeps `10 rows` at the same time. But in `cellForRowAtIndex` everything loads ok, for all rows. I keep all the data in some `NSMutableArray`, to access the data I need with `[indexPath row]`.

I have already spend some time looking for similar post, but don't find anything like this.

any help will be appreciate. Thanks!

Some code:

```
//    in .h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PullRefreshTableViewController.h"
#import "DetalleMailViewController.h"

@interface MensajesTableViewController : PullRefreshTableViewController <DetalleMailViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mailAuthors;
@property (nonatomic) int row_tabla_delete;

- (IBAction)presentMenu:(id)sender;

@end

//in .m make the synthesize of mailAuthors and some relevant code:


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    //This gesture works fine
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(presentMenu:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.5; //seconds
    lpgr.numberOfTouchesRequired =1;
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *idCell = @"mailTableCell";
    MailCell *celda = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idCell];
    if(celda == nil){
        celda = [[MailCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:idCell];
    }

    celda.mailAuthor.text = [self.mailAuthors objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    return celda;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //I really use a segue here, but for the sake of simplicity, I just put a trace, never called for rows 10, 20, 30... The segue works fine the rest of the time...
    NSLog(@"tapped %d", [indexPath row]);
}

- (IBAction)presentMenu:(id)sender {

    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        CGPoint p = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];

        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

        if (indexPath != nil){
            self.row_tabla_delete = [indexPath row];
        }

        //some code to delete the row

    }
}
```

In `MailCell`.h`I have the`UILabel`for mailAuthor as a property, and linked in the storyboard with the UILabel inside the`UITableViewCell`. In the storyboard, I have a`TableView`Controller linked to my own class "`MensajeTableViewController`", the`UITableViewCell`to my "`MailCell`". 
If there is some need to add some other relevant code, or something else, please Help me.

Comment: I have edited my post to add some code so maybe it's easier to see what happen

Comment: Make sure you are not adding any gesture recognisers to the TableCells or Table itself.

Comment: You've changed your -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: by removing the segue and replacing it with an NSLog statement. Are you saying that the bug is still there with the NSLog statement? That's hard to believe, so if you don't mind, please clarify.

Comment: In the comments I said that I still have the segue there, and works fine except for rows 10,20,30... those times, nothing happens neither the segue nor de nslog statement. I really don't remember if I did the test deleting the segue, because this is a problem unresolved for me, since summer 2012, with ios 5, and now there is ios 7 and i didn't test my program with it, but i really needed a segue there, so your comment don't help me about the problem, because if i cannot include a segue like that, i wish to know how is the good way to do what I want without find this kind of problem.

Comment: You should add all the codes pertaining to the delegate methods of your tableview, in particular - How many sections do you have in your tableview ? The 10,20,30 does not make sense. But if the 10 20 30th row are section headers - it will not be selectable.   Also just curious, you setup a long press gesture to allow deletions of row. I find this odd because the default gestures for editable tableview has a very cool interface for deletions using a swipe gesture

Comment: @Paulo has some good points, it's also possible that the Gesture recognizer is blocking the touches through to those rows as you are adding it to the tableView view. Try adding it to the cell content view instead ?